# How do I solve $x:y:z=3:4:5$, $z+2y-3x=16$ then $y=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x:y:z=3:4:5,\quad z+2y-3x=16 \quad \text{then}\quad  y=?
$$
The answer is 16.

But how to solve?

I am preparing for exam.

> This question comes from metropol mathematics 1 textbook.

Comment: I would start by setting $x=3t$, $y=4t$ and $z=5t$ and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=3k, y=4k, z=5k, z+2y-3x=16 \implies 4k=16 \implies k=4.$ Then $y=16$.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve as in high school:
$$\frac x3=\frac y4=\frac z 5=\frac{z+2y-3x}{5+2\cdot 4-3\cdot 3}=\frac{16}{4}=4,$$
whence $x,y,z$ in one go.

Answer (score 0):

From $x:y:z=3:4:5$

Thus, $x:y:z=12:16:20$

Therefore $z+2y-3x=20+2(16)-3(12)=52-36=16$

We have $y=16$